# Create a session for external domain which is using the same rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have configured two domains **`domain1.com @D1`** and **`domain2.com @D2`** in nginx which are using the same rails app+DB. The users **`U1`** and **`U2`** are belongs to **`D1`** domain and the user **`U3`** belongs to **`D2`** domain.

I don't know how to create a session for domain **`D2`** and redirect to the same when the User **`U3`** tried to login through domain **`D1`** since both have same login page and the user belongs to **`D2`**. Any solution pls?

**Note:** The session should not be shared between the domains since both are using the same app+DB.

**Stack:** Rails 3+, Ruby 1.9.2, Unicorn, nginx